# SQL Server 2008 Pivot Function

Tags: sql-server-2008

Team,

I have two tables

Customer Table

```
Cust ID Firstname  Surname
1        Maryam     Sidat
2        Alex       Clegg
```

Child Table

```
Child ID    Cust ID   Child Firstname  Child Surname    DOB
99          1         Humi             Sidat            01 Jan 2003
98          1         Adam             Sidat            27 Feb 1998
97          2         Sam              Clegg            05 Mar 2000
```

How do I write a query which will display the results like thus

```
1   Maryam   Sidat    Humi Sidat  01 Jan 2003    Adam Sidat 27 Feb 1998     
2   Alex     Clegg    Sam  Clegg  0 Mar 2000
```

I.E display 1 row for each customer with their children in the same row rather than

```
1   Maryam   Sidat    Humi Sidat  01 Jan 2003    
1   Maryam   Sidat    Adam Sidat  27 Feb 1998     
2   Alex     Clegg    Sam  Clegg  0 Mar 2000
```

The data is just an illustration. In the real world i will not know the names of the customers and how many children they have.

Any help/quidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't...

To create this type of result you'd have to create dynamic sql and execute. SQL Server is not able to generate results like that.